# Need to display a div when I click a link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

For some dumb practices in which I am not allowed to use alert or any Js dialog box I have to make the following magic happen:

1.Make a div with a link, in this case its the one called info.
2.Made a invisible div, that would be my "PopUp" with some rubbish info inside.
3.When I click on the link info, the invisible div should materialize.

While simple and and even fairly obvious I am having a bit of trouble getting the logic of how to make such thing happen. If it helps me save face I just started programming..like 1 month ago and just HTML CSS, I am new to this whole Js universe.

This is my code as of now:

```
<div class="scroll-area" id="lista">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Item #1</p>
        <p class="info"><a href="#" id="lnkInfo">Info</p>
        </a>
        <p class="info"><a href="#">Take</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Item #2</p>
        <p class="info"><a href="#">Info</p>
        </a>
        <p class="info"><a href="#">Take</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here comes the *groans* "PopUp"...

```
<div class="popUp">
    <ul>
        <li>BLA BLA</li>
        <li>BLA BLA/li>
        <li>BLA BLA</li>
        <li>BLA!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS just in case.

```
.popUp {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

And what I though would be a start to the JS:

```
var elementPopUp = document.getElementById('lnkInfo');

elementoPopUp.addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate() {
    document.getElementById('popUp').className += ' show';
}
```

Comment: `"For some dumb practices in which I am not allowed to use alert or any Js dialog box I have to make the following magic happen"` Are you saying that not being able to use alert is **bad**?  Because if you are, we may have words...  For debug purposes, you should try to use `console.log()` since it isn't nearly as obtrusive as an `alert()` As to how to create an element, you should start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: It is merely a example, don't hit me D;  and I don't need it for debug or anything of that sort, I am talking about Javascript 101 at its best. I just need what it says on the post, for the div to show when I click the info link.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery? :)

Comment: There is no id called popUp in your HTML.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper the fun thing, you made the right code only with a few typos like: `elementoPopUp` and you shoud add an ID to your popup div. ([fixed these typos in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awLAY/))

Comment: Unless there's a reason not to, I'd recommend learning/using jQuery to make things like this quicker to implement. But a couple of hints: you've confused id and class for popUp. Also you have a typo in element(o)PopUp and I think that adding a class will mean the element has both classes. Finally, have you tried the code? Posting what happens, e.g. any messages in the console, can really help clarify a question. Good luck.

Comment: I am not allowed to use jQuery as of yet...perhaps next week >.> I also corrected the id on the html and the css thanks, now I will try with the fiddle lionel was kind enough to do for me.

Comment: Chris I did try but I ma using sublime text 3 >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** you have syntax bugs in your html code fix and you are using `getElementById` to get element but you set `popUp` as class change it to id

```
<div class="scroll-area" id="lista">
    <div class="box"> 
        <p>Item #1</p>
        <p class="info"><a href="#" id="lnkInfo">Info
        </a></p>
        <p class="info"><a href="#">Take
        </a></p>
    </div> 
    <div class="box">
        <p>Item #2</p>
        <p class="info"><a href="#">Info</a></p>

        <p class="info"><a href="#">Take</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popup" >
    <ul>
        <li>BLA BLA</li>
        <li>BLA BLA</li>
        <li>BLA BLA</li>
        <li>BLA!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css

```
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    display: none;
}

#popup.show {
    display: block;
}
```

and javascript

```
var elementPopUp = document.getElementById('lnkInfo');

elementPopUp.addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate() {
  var d = document.getElementById("popup");

  d.classList.add("show");
}
```

Comment: My mistake, nevertheless it still doesn't solve the Js part I think. I will go and try

Comment: you haven't any element with `popUp` id in your code, change `class="popUp"` to `id="popUp"`

Comment: Corrected! Thanks, it isn't working but at least that is one error less.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper check Updated version ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you do this:

```
<div class="scroll-area" id="lista">
         <div class="box">
            <p>Item #1</p>
            <p class="info"><a href="#" id="lnkInfo" onclick="validate()">Info</p></a>
            <p class="info"><a href="#">Take</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Item #2</p>
            <p class="info"><a href="#">Info</p></a>
            <p class="info"><a href="#">Take</p></a>
        </div>
              </div>
```

And make the javascript this:

```
function validate(){

document.getElementById('popUp').style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
```

That should work.
I have not tested it, so I may have a syntax or two wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to affect element style through JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
<a id="shower" href="">
    show
</a>

<br>
<a id="hider" href="">
    hide
</a>

<br>
<div id="popup" class="hide">Hello</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("shower").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("popup");
    myDiv.className = "";
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById("hider").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("popup");
    myDiv.className = "hide";
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, with this I will work a way to hide the popup@

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of what I'd do:

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="clickMe">clickMe</a>

<div id="showMe">showMe</div>
```

The CSS:

```
display:none;
```

The JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "block";
}
```

Here is a [fiddle to show the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/5fbew/)

Hope this helps ;)